# Is Android API callback based?

Tags: java, android

Say I have a very simple Android app that has just one activity - the activity displays a plain screen. Lets say I have overridden the onCreate() method of the activity and it simply sets the screen as described in activity_main.xml and then returns as shown below:

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        //boolean BT_success = turnBluetoothOn();
    }
```

In a desktop Java (or C or Python) program, execution starts at the "main" method/function and the program finishes executing when main has finished executing (and once all the functions called by main have returned). In this simple app described above, when the common set of callback functions like onCreate(), onStart() and onResume() are finished executing, is there any part of my code that is executing?

In this sense, there is no "main" method, like in the case of desktop Java, C or Python, right? Even if we had a couple of buttons in this main screen, we would have callback functions for those buttons.

So is it fair to say that the Android API callback based in the sense that an app developer has to implement certain callback functions (and those can in turn call other functions)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not in the way Win32 is. For one thing, the Android flavor of Java doesn't readily accommodate the notion of a canned function; it has neither delegates (C#) nor functors (C++, Python) nor function pointers (C, C++).

The Android API is still event driven, like most GUI systems are; but the primary ways for you to provide hooks into your code to the framework are:

- inheriting from library classes and then overriding functions that were meant to be overridden;
- implementing abstract interfaces in your classes (possibly anonymous) and providing those objects to the framework.

This is, generally, the Java way.

EDIT: depends on your definition of callback :) Normally, when people say that, they mean a function. In this sense, it's not callback-based. But if you mean "the framework calls you whenever something interesting takes place", then yes, it is. Event-driven, like I said.

EDIT2: Preamble: C has function pointers. It's a datatype that you can initialize with a function name, pass around like a primitive value, and then call with arguments at some point down the road. The call will be received by the function that the pointer was initialized with originally.

Windows, like Android, is an event-driven GUI system. The event-driven nature of Windows is implemented mainly via said function pointers - you pass a pointer to your function to the framework, the framework calls it back when something interesting occurs. This was designed in mid-1980's, before the advent of object oriented languages.

Now, those functions that are meant to be called by the framework are referred to as "callback functions" or simply "callbacks". I come from the Windows background, so for me, "callback" primarily means "callback function". As opposed to Android-style callback objects (is that even a term?).

Comment: Got it. Thanks. Could you elaborate a bit more on what people normally mean when they say callbacks? (as opposed to "But if you mean..")

Answer (score 1):

This is not dissimilar to the way any GUI application/framework is designed. Even Java Swing works in a similar fashion. You implement the "callbacks" that are hooked to UI control events, and your "main" function usually only serves to kick off the main event loop and exit. Note that here, when main() exits, the program itself does not exit.

Answer (score 1):

To simply answer your question, yes it is based on callbacks. You specify which activity should be the starting point for your application in your androidmanifest.xml. This activity's onCreate() is called to initialize the layout. Every interaction that you perform on the screen triggers a callback (which you will override to implement what you need). But just because the main activity exits does not mean that the application will exit.

This is where you go into the activity lifecycle. All activities sit on the main thread in a stack like manner. When one activity is killed, you go to the next activity in the thread and so on. The application itself exits when all it's activities in this stack have been killed or Android decides to terminate it. Keep in mind that you might normally expect onDestroy() to be called when Android terminates the application but this is not the case - Android may or may not call onDestroy(). In this case, there was no callback for the exit.

Answer (score 0):

I would say the Android API is heavily based on Extension. You almost always have to extend their Classes and override their methods.

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
```

Is a call to the Super Class method that would normally be hidden by you override. You are, however, free to call back to classes that provide the logic you need but you are not forced to. I recommend that you do, and that you put those Classes under UnitTest.

Comment: I see how it makes heavy use of extension. But my question is: is it callback based as well? In the simple app described above, is no code running after initial setup has been done?

Comment: "is it callback based as well?" Not anymore than any other Java application IMO.